# How to add a counter that will show how many text matches were found

Tags: javascript

How do you write in Javascript a counter that will show how many text matches were found or replaced? I'm kind of stuck.

```js
var haystackText = "";
function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
     if (haystackText.length == 0) {
          haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
     }
     var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");     
     var replaced = "";
     if (replacement.length > 0) {
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
     }
     else {
          var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
     }
     document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<br>
<table>
<tr><td>Find</td><td><input id="needle" name="needle" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Replacment</td><td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Find" onClick="findMyText(document.getElementById('needle').value, document.getElementById('replacement').value);">
► Run code snippetCopy snippet to answer
```

Comment: The second argument String.replace() can be a function.  You could use that to count how many replacements happened.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `match` to find the length of the found (and/or replaced) instances of search term `needle`:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=button]').addEventListener('click', findMyText);

function findMyText(e) {
     var needle = document.querySelector('#needle').value; 
     var replacement = document.querySelector('#replacement').value;
     var haystackText = document.querySelector('#haystack').textContent;
     var match = new RegExp(needle, 'ig'); 
     var foundlen = (haystackText.match(match) || []).length;
     //                           ^ use match
     var replaced = '';
     if (replacement.length > 0) {
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
     }
     else {
          var boldText = "<div style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
     }
     document.querySelector('#haystack').innerHTML = replaced;
     document.querySelector('#found').textContent = 
           ' ['+ needle + ']: ' + foundlen + ' found';
}
```

```css
#found {color: red; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<br>
<table>
<tr><td>Find</td><td><input id="needle" name="needle" type="text"><span id="found"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Replacment</td><td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Find">
```

Answer (score 1):

try to count the yellow div, I add to this div a class then i count it 
working here:

```js
var haystackText = "";
var count = "";
function findMyText(needle, replacement) {
     if (haystackText.length == 0) {
          haystackText = document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML;
     }
      
     var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");     
     var replaced = "";
     if (replacement.length > 0) {
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);
       
     }
     else {
          var boldText = "<div class='count' style=\"background-color: yellow; display: inline; font-weight: bold;\">" + needle + "</div>";
          replaced = haystackText.replace(match, boldText);
     }
     document.getElementById("haystack").innerHTML = replaced;
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("count")
    count = arr.length
     document.getElementById('founded').innerHTML = "The number of "+ needle+"is : "+ count;
    //alert(count);
}
```

```html
<div id="haystack">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
<br>
<table>
<tr><td>Find</td><td><input id="needle" name="needle" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Replacment</td><td><input id="replacement" name="replacement" type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Find" onClick="findMyText(document.getElementById('needle').value, document.getElementById('replacement').value);">
► Run code snippetCopy snippet to answer
<div id="founded"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome, enjoy coding and feel free to upvote my answer